# Semi-Transparent div background on top of img tag

Tags: html, css, image, image-rotation

How do I get a div background image to show above a img html tag. The reason for wanting to do this is for a semitransparent texture that overlays rotating images in a banner. I don't want to have to cut the texture with the image each time. That way adding/updating images in the future would be faster. I have tried the advice given in this post, but did not seem to work: [CSS show div background image on top of other contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556656/css-show-div-background-image-on-top-of-other-contained-elements). Thanks for any help.

html:

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
    <div id="slider">
        <span id="slider-background">
            <img src="/_images/rotating-banner/001.jpg" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sliderFrame {position:relative;width:850px;margin: 0 auto;} 

#slider {
  width:850px;height:470px;/* Make it the same size as your images */
  background:#fff url(/_images/marqueeLayout/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;/*make the image slider center-aligned */
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

#slider-background{
  position:absolute;
  background: url(/_images/marqueeLayout/MarqueeTexture.png) no-repeat;
  width: 850px;
  height: 470px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

link to live site: http://lltc.designangler.com/

Answer (score 1):

try:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrappaer{display:inline-block; position:relative; width:100px; height:100px;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;}
#img{display:block; position:absolute; z-index:1}
#overlay{display:block; position:absolute; z-index:2
     opacity:0.3;
     filter:alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
```

make sure to adjust wrapper,img and overlay sizes, add your images etc'.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the opacity of the div element? 
Edit:
After rereading your question, I believe this may not be what you're looking for.  Have you tried explicitly setting the z-index of the slider element in the CSS as well?

Comment: I did, but the issue is that the div background has the transparency and the image does not. That is why I would like the div background image on top of the img tag.

Comment: Check out this site:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

It has editable code as well...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by using an img of the background inside a div instead of making it a background image. My updated code is below:

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
<div id="overlay"><img src="/_images/marqueeLayout/MarqueeTexture.png" /></div>
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="/_images/rotating-banner/001.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width: 850px;
  height: 470px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image, as its name suggest, can **never** be in front of the child elements. Therefore, you will need to rely on absolute positioning to overlay that background image over the slideshow:

```
#sliderFrame {
    position: relative;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#slider {
    width:850px;
    height:470px;
    background:#fff url(/_images/marqueeLayout/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}
#slider-background {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 850px;
    height: 470px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#slider-background:before {
    background: url(/_images/marqueeLayout/MarqueeTexture.png) no-repeat;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
#slider-background img {
    display: block;
}
```

I have chosen to use a pseudo element that is positioned absolutely over the `#slider-background` element itself, and it is stretch to the element's dimension by setting all four offsets to 0. Remember that you will also need to declare the `#slider-background` and its child `<img>` element as block-level elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/XJFqc/