# Make image link override background image on top of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div block which shows a preview image to a video (YouTube), the problem is that this preview thumbnail generated by CMS, it doesn't give the YouTube play icon in the middle of it, so it doesn't look like a video, but just a plain image.

So I came up with a solution (top answer [CSS show div background image on top of other contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556656/css-show-div-background-image-on-top-of-other-contained-elements)), by adding an empty span and giving it a background, that YouTube play icon and position absolute and positioning it in the middle of that image preview thumbnail. All looks great, now the problem is that background is not a link, the thumbnail is a link to the video, so that transparent icon hides the thumbnail link below it.

[image]

Comment: You could try this solution:
[Click through a div to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed that pointer-events: none; didn't even know such rule existed! Can you post this as answer please so I could choose it.

Comment: Sadly, it's not working on IE.

Comment: Depending on the HTML, you might be able to nest your play button element inside the clickable element? What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: In that post was mentioned to use an IE filter. Doesn't this work either on IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post:
[Click through a div to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

It works, if you add the following CSS attribute:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Here is also a post about the IE compatibility: [fromanegg](http://fromanegg.com/post/32669641429/clicking-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)