# CSS background image on top of <img>

Tags: html, css

**How does one repeat this 1px x 1px CSS background image on top of the HTML `<img>`?**

http://jsfiddle.net/hjv74tdw/1/

I came across [CSS show div background image on top of other contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556656/css-show-div-background-image-on-top-of-other-contained-elements), however it seems to require an extra div. Ideally I wish I didn't have to use a div at all, but according to [CSS Background-image over HTML img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700136/css-background-image-over-html-img) that's not really possible, at least not for a 100% width responsive scenario.

```css
.test {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1/1) repeat;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
}
.test img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
</div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use a pseudo-element. In this example, the `:after` pseudo element is absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent element. It takes the dimensions of the entire parent element, and the size of the parent element is determined by the size of the child `img` element.

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.test:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/20x20/1) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
</div>
```

As a side note, your example wasn't working for a couple of reasons. The parent element has a background image, but since the child element establishs a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) *within* the parent element, it's not possible for the parent's background image to appear *above* the child `img` element (unless you were to completely hide the `img` element). This is why the `z-index`s weren't working as expected.

In addition, the `img` element was absolutely positioned. In doing so, it is removed from the normal flow, and since it was the only child element, the parent element therefore collapses upon itself and it doesn't have any dimensions. Thus, the background image doesn't show up. To work around this, you would either have to set explicit dimensions on the parent element (`height`/`width`), or you could remove the absolute positioning on the child `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, is to set `content` to empty and set a background, for example:

```
img {
    background: url(...) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/infous/effmea8x/

In this demo the first image is standard but with unproportional width and hight, the second one is with the background. The first one is scaled badly, the second one is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did for my solution. Essentially, I'm using the "IMG" as a placeholder. So that my Background image maintains the correct proportions as the browser resizes.

```
.image-overlay {
  background-image: url("insert image here");
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.image-overlay img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="category-overlay">
    <img src="/images/placeholder.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```