# show product image as radio/checkbox and show tick mark when checked

Tags: html, css, image

I want to add an Background image on the `<img>` attribute. I want to show the tick image center of the twitter image. But, the tick image or background-image is doesn't show in here.

```css
img{
  background-image:url(https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2692824-green-check-mark-symbol-over-white-background.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:20%;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://hakin9.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/twitter-150x150.png"  />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image on top of <img>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710659/css-background-image-on-top-of-img)

Comment: I can't find my answer from there. @ovokuro

Comment: Quentin's answer below explains exactly why your code isn't working. If you can't / don't want to edit the image, then you will need to overlay the tick using a method from the question I linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a custom checkbox ensure the following:

- Need at least one checkbox and one label
- Place checkbox before the label
- The checkbox should have `display:none`
- The label should have `for={Id of checkbox}`
- If the label is the next thing after checkbox, then your checked style should look something like: ex. `chx:checked + label {...`
- If the label and checkbox are on the same level but not next to each other: ex. `chx:checked ~ label {...`
- Those are the two most common layouts but not the only ones.

### Demo

```css
.chx {
  display: none
}

.label {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://hakin9.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/twitter-150x150.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: none
}

.chx:checked+.label img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}
```

```html
<input id='chx' class='chx' type='checkbox'>


<label class='label' for='chx'><img src='https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2692824-green-check-mark-symbol-over-white-background.jpg' width='50'></label>
```

Comment: @acoder what browser are you using I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Oh. Yes, I see.

Comment: But, I don't need the full background-image(green check image) . I want to show this only center of the Twitter image smally.

Comment: Firefox works as well, I'm too lazy to dig up my Mac to test Safari.

Comment: Yeah @zer00ne, you are awesome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158625/discussion-between-acoder-and-zer00ne).

Comment: oh. Can use Radio Button as checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The centre of the twitter image that you are using is *white*.

A background image will only show through areas of an image that are *transparent*.

You would need to edit the image to change those pixels to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the twitter logo has a white background so you can't see the tick behind it.

It's also impossible with just one img element to get the background-image on top of the content. You need to introduce another element like a div like so:

*I have decreased the size of the tick so you can still see that the twitter icon is there*

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.test:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url('https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2692824-green-check-mark-symbol-over-white-background.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://hakin9.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/twitter-150x150.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. I want to show the tick icon center the twitter image. I don't need this full size background @RyanEarnshaw

Comment: @acoder I changed my answer, runt he snippet now :)

Comment: It shows the checkmark in the background and the "Error could not display image" icon in the foreground. Where's the twitter icon?

Comment: Oho. I have only need the `<img>` not `<div>` .

Comment: @acoder what you're asking for is 100% impossible then. You can't have the background-image on top of the actual content of an element

Comment: Okay. I use image as radio button. So, I need when user check the image a tick image should show in top right. Can you help me about this?

Comment: Hi , @RyanEarnshaw